# How to identify if a .ppt file is in 2003 format or 97 format or 95 format

Tags: file, format, powerpoint

I have a xxx.ppt file. I need to identify if this file is in 2003 format or 97 format or 95 format or a version older than that. I tried checking file properties, it simply says Microsoft Powerpoint. No version mentioned. I tried with Apache POI and got the version number something like this **"ppt version[50334156]"**. I couldn't find any specification documents for pre 97 format files either. Working with these binary files is such a pain.

Comment: Are you really likely to run into all that many PPT 95 format files?  Since 97/2000/2002/2003 all share the same format, at least those shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi Steve, i do care about 97 and above format files only. But when i get a bunch of test files i need to filter out all the pre 97 format files, which is where i am struck now. I do not know how to distinguish a .ppt file created using office 95 vs office 2003.

Comment: It may help to know that newer versions of PPT simply won't open PPT 95 files, so you could try to open the file, handle any errors that result (which might be because it's PPT95 or might be other problems)

Comment: Will check that option Steve. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you need to do this but I found it extreamly interesting (Can it be done?) So I wrote this very ugly powershell hack.

```
 $shell = new-object -com shell.application
 Rename-Item C:\Temp\Presentation1.ppt C:\Temp\Presentation1.zip
 $zip = $shell.NameSpace(“C:\Temp\Presentation1.zip”)
 mkdir C:\temp\ziptest
 foreach($item in $zip.items())
 {
    $shell.Namespace(“C:\temp\ziptest”).copyhere($item)
 }

 $file = Get-Content C:\temp\ziptest\docprops\app.xml | Select-String -Pattern ("<AppVersion>([\s\S]*?)</AppVersion>") 
 Remove-Item -Recurse -Force C:\temp\ziptest\ 
 clear 
 echo $file.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

To use it you will have to add a function that reads your ppt files into a variable and then loops through this snippet, the snippet will rename them to .zip (and by this enable us to read the xml files from the ppt) get the app.xml and give you the version number (Office95 = 7.0, Office 97 (8.0), Office 97 Powered by Word 98 (8.5), Office 2000 (9.0), Office XP (10.0),Office 2003 (11.0),Office 2007 (12.0), Office 2010 (14.0), Office 2013 (15.0))

Comment: If you can read the xml files within the PPTX (note: NOT PPT) then it's a PowerPoint 2007 or later file.  Earlier versions (2003 and prior) use a completely different format; they're not XML internally, and they're not ZIP files.

Comment: Hi Karl, Thanks for your reply. Your script will work for **.PPTX** files, which is based on OOXML. But PPT files are binary streams, there won't be any app.xml file inside.